# UIPopoverController not dismissing in xCode 5/ios7

Tags: xcode4.5, popover

Since upgrading to iOS 7 and xCode 5 my popovers are not dismissing when the user selects an item. They have to tap outside of the popover to get it to go away.

In the following the UITableViewController is foundPatientsViewController and I am creating the propover like this from my root view controller...

```
    TodaysPatientsViewController *foundPatientsViewController =[[TodaysPatientsViewController alloc] init];
    foundPatientsViewController.patientList = patientList;
    foundPatientsViewController.delegate = self;
    foundPatientsViewController.patientNameOnly = YES;
    UIPopoverController *foundPatientsPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:foundPatientsViewController];
    foundPatientsPopOver.delegate = self;
    foundPatientsViewController.myPO = foundPatientsPopOver;
    [foundPatientsPopOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:findPatientButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [foundPatientsPopOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, popOverHeight) animated:NO];
    [foundPatientsViewController release];
```

In foundPatientsViewController I have...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [myPO dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
  [self.delegate patienSelectedForDisplay:self withPatientNumber:[patientNumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] patientName:[patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
}
```

What has changed?

Thanks,

John

Comment: did you find an explanation of this behaviour?